# "not permitted" vs. "not allowed" vs. [something else] in a table of permitted bacterial counts

Tags: phrase-request, translation

Let's say I have a document, a specification for a vitamin mix for addition into animal fodder. This document has a table listing the maximum permitted contents of bacteria in the mix.

The first line reads: "Maximum overall bacterial count, in cells/g: 500 000".

The second, third, and fourth to tenth lines read "E.Coli and coliform bacteria", "Proteus", etc. The column value is "not allowed" for each of these, meaning that it's a no-no to have any such bacteria in the mix.

Is "not allowed" a proper combination of words? I came up with "not permitted" as an alternative, but there could be more idiomatic word combinations.

The Russian original is "не допускаются" ('are not admitted', in a blunt translation; meaning the very existence of such bacteria in a sample of the product is a no-no)

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with _'not allowed'_.

Comment: You could use '**forbidden**', although that sounds very commanding and strict.

Comment: I would prefer _not allowed_ to _not permitted,_ but I would prefer the numeral `0` over either one.

Comment: @Adam - thank you! I also thought about using the zero, but was afraid to stray too far from the Russian original.

Comment: The U.S. EPA uses `zero` in its drinking water contaminant tables: https://www.epa.gov/ground-water-and-drinking-water/table-regulated-drinking-water-contaminants

Comment: @Adam - you might post that as an answer!

Comment: You could also say "None permitted" or "None allowed" if you are using a count. How many red ones are allowed? None (are allowed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many similar examples out there:

The [United States EPA](https://www.epa.gov/ground-water-and-drinking-water/table-regulated-drinking-water-contaminants) sets standards for drinking water contaminants:

> **Di(2-ethylhexyl) phthalate**    `zero`

I have seen this switched to the numeral `0` in city water quality fact sheets.

---

In strict terms, though, we can't say that a concentration is zero - only that it cannot be detected.  So some standards will say *non-detectable.*  That invites the question of how hard one has to look before declaring something non-detectable.

The [U.S. FDA](http://www.fda.gov/Food/GuidanceRegulation/FSMA/ucm334552.htm) sets limits for bacteria in animal-sourced fertilizer with that issue specifically adressed:

> **L. monocytogenes**   *Not detected using a method that can detect one CFU per five gram analytical portion*

*Not permitted* would be well understood by the public, but doesn't really specify how to determine the absence.

---

The examples above reflect the usage when issuing regulations.  If you are looking for a way to provide testing results, it is common to report non-detects as being less than the detect threshold.  For instance, if your test can detect 0.1 ppm listeria, you could report a non-detect as:

> **Listeria**   `<0.1 ppm`

---

Answer (score 1):

Not allowed is a more informal way of saying not permitted. Not permitted is more formal, as shown by the definition - officially allow (someone) to do something.